# Splitting text to columns in Excel

Tags: excel, text, cell

I have a column in `Excel` that consists of data in the following format: "NAME OF BAND Album Title". I'd like to split this cell into two--one for the all-caps band name and another for Album Title. Below are a few examples from the data:

```
Column A
ABSORBED Demo '98 
ABSTRACT CELL THEORY Act
ABSTRACT SATAN Elite 7512 
ABSTRACT SATAN Aryan Blitzkrieg Union 
ABSTRACT SATAN Satanic Blood Circle 
ABSTRACT SHADOWS Symphony of Hakel
```

Splitting by space doesn't work since bands have varying numbers of words in their name. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a formula solution. No VBA required.

Assuming your list starts in cell A1, enter the following formula in cell B1:

```
=LEFT(A1,MATCH(,--(CODE(MID(A1,ROW(OFFSET($A$1,,,LEN(A1))),1))<96),)-3)
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

And then in cell C1, enter this:

```
=MID(A1,MATCH(,--(CODE(MID(A1,ROW(OFFSET($A$1,,,LEN(A1))),1))<96),)-1,99)
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now select the range B1:C1 and copy downward as far as needed.

.

**Here is how they work**. We'll discuss the first formula.

The MID function splits the value of cell A1 into individual characters. The CODE function returns the ASCII code number for each char. We test each code number to see if it is less than 96, which is "a" the first lower case char.

This gives us an array of Boolean values (TRUE or FALSE), one Booelan value for each char in cell A1.

We convert the Booleans to ONES and ZEROES by the double unary (--).

We search the array for the location of the first ZERO by using the MATCH function.

The end of the contiguous upper case letters is three char locations prior to the location returned by MATCH.

That's it.

What makes all of that possible is the array at the heart of the formula produced by the ROW/OFFSET combination. In conjunction with the LEN function, this combo produces a vector array that looks something like {1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11}. That array's last and largest number is equal to the length of the value in cell A1.

.

**UPDATE**

Here is a sample workbook showing these formulas work on the question's example data:  http://www.excelhero.com/samples/torentino_excelhero.xlsx

Comment: Hi Excel Hero, can you explain the formula in B1? I'm having trouble understanding the logic. Thanks.

Comment: @Sergio Please see the updated lower section of my answer for an explanation.

Comment: @ExcelHero thanks but the resultant splitting doesn't work properly. I end up with two cells but the BAND NAME Album Title in the original cell gets transformed into BD NA in one cell and no album title in the other.

Comment: @torentino It works. Here is the  spreadsheet so you can see:  http://www.excelhero.com/samples/torentino_excelhero.xlsx

Comment: @torentino Were you able to get this going with my sample workbook?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @ExcelHero. No wonder I was struggling to understand the logic, it is extremely complex, really clever stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might split off the band names from the albums.

```
Sub splt()
    Dim rw As Long, p As Long, r As Long, sp As Long, v As Long
    Dim bnd As String, ttl As String, tmp As Variant

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For rw = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            p = 1
            bnd = vbNullString
            ttl = Trim(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2) & Chr(32)
            tmp = Split(ttl)
            For v = LBound(tmp) To UBound(tmp)
                If UCase(tmp(v)) = tmp(v) Then
                    bnd = Join(Array(bnd, tmp(v)), Chr(32))
                Else
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next v
            .Cells(rw, 2) = bnd
            .Cells(rw, 3) = Trim(Right(ttl, Len(ttl) - Len(bnd)))
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```